# Chrome JavaScript Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am new to chrome dev tools (and coding). I am trying to run this javascript function in the chrome dev tools JS console and it won't work, it is code I have copied line for line from an online tutorial to check if its working. (i'm guessing its a dev tools setting or something as the code works on the online tutorial)

Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
var output = [];
var count = 1;

function fizzBuzz() {
  output.push(count);
  count++;

  console.log(output);
}
```

Comment: Save the file and try again.  By the way, it's best to place the code in your question. That way we can attempt to duplicate the problem you see.

Comment: Thanks so much ill post code snippet next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the file and run it again by clicking the "play" icon.

[image]

Comment: awesome thanks so much! I was googling it for over 2 hours 

Comment: @njdeane consider an upvote also if the answer was helpful.

Comment: Thanks Rumesh, I did upvote but as I have less than 15 points it isn't recorded, but the points are given.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialise the variables in Console.